Rancher desktop I'm unable to ping my node
Operating System: Windows 11
Rancher Version: 1.16
Kubernetes Version: 1.31.1
Assigned Node IP: 192.168.127.2
Issue: I'm unable to ping my node (192.168.127.2).
Why I need this: I added some entries in my hosts file, such as:
192.168.127.2 mytestapp.com

I've also set up Traefik to handle the domain and service.
Earlier, the node IP was something like 172.31.141.244, and I was able to ping it and access my app using the domain I configured in the hosts file.
Question: what could I be missing or overlooking in this new setup?
Thanks in advance,
Timur
